# How to display a modal (box) on click of @Html.ActionLink when having multiples entries in table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Hello I am new to MVC and doing my assignments. I got stuck at what to do when I have multiple entries in table, and on click of `@Html.ActionLink` i want to call and html modal and perform some operations.

Calling modal and performing operation must be done by AJAX is requirement.

Below code is of my **Index.cshtml** file.

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Author)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-list", id = item.Id })
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

I am confused that how to get record of particular entry and perform operation like Edit/Delete on it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly U want to set a hidden value for your id of table from model. for that value set a data-id atrr. like this :

<`input type="hidden" value="@Model.Id" class="modelId" data-id="@Model.Id" />`

and add below code:

```
 @section Scripts{
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(window).load(function () {
                    var val = $(".modelId").attr("data-id");
                    $(".btnRemove").click(function (event) {
                        $(this).addClass("groupId");
                        event.preventDefault();
                        $(".modal").show();
                        $(".btnClose").click(function () {
                            $(".modal").slideUp(200);
                        })
                        $(".close").click(function () {
                            $(".modal").slideUp(200);
                        })
                        $("#confirmed").click(function () {
                            //var value =$(this).find(".btnRemove").attr("data-val");
                            var value = $(".groupId").attr("data-val");
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")",
                                type: 'POST',
                                cache:false,
                                data: { id: value, userId:val},

                                success: function () { // if true (1)
                                    setTimeout(function () {
                                        window.location = '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { id =Model.Id })';
                                    }, 1000);
                                    }
                        });
                    })
                    })
                });

            });

    </script>

        }
```

The above will go through a process like this:
**click on delete** > **show a modal for confirmation** > **while click on ok it will call the ajax function** > **in ajax success function reloading the page**.

For this You should have a Modal like this below:

```
<div class="modal modal-success">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align:center;color:black;font-size:30px"><b>Confrimation</b></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p style="color:white;text-align:center;font-size:large"><b>Are you Sure to Remove this Group</b></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline pull-left btnClose" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline" id="confirmed">Ok</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

And change your `@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-list", id = item.Id })`

like this :

```
<button class="btn btn-warning btnRemove remove"  type="button" data-val="@item.ID"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Delete</button>
```

to show a list in modal you may create a PartialViewResult in controller. For me its like this to show members in a modal.

```
public PartialViewResult GroupMembers(int grid)
    {
        groupSearchModel model = new groupSearchModel();
        model.fetchGroupMembersList = Functions.CommonFunctions.fetchGroupMemberList(grid, 1);
        return PartialView("GroupMembers",model);
    }
```

then in your ajax call you may call this controller. Then you modal will populated with the details required.

Comment: Okay, how to display popup on click of "Details" link? after that may be this could work.

Comment: @wacky_coder : review my answer for edits that i have made.